# Qt debugging crashes/quits python and end up not debugging properly (e.g. not stopping at breakpoints)

Tags: python, c++, qt, debugging

I'm exploring the Qt framework and I'm learning about debugging a Qt application.
I've set a breakpoint on a line in the source code and click the "Start Debugging" icon/button.  The console prints "Debugging starts"...and then a Dialog Box appears stating:
"Python quit unexpectedly while using _lldb.so plug-in".

Then the whole program just runs without stopping at the breakpoint I've set.
How do I fix this problem with Qt?

Thank you...

I'm using a MacBookPro running on OS X Yosemite.

I'm using:
Qt Creator 3.3.0 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.4.0 (Clang 6.0 (Apple), 64 bit)

Built on Dec 8 2014 at 15:34:58

From revision d36c4d87db

Copyright 2008-2014 Digia Plc. All rights reserved.

How do I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the code you want to debug is executed before the error?

Comment: There is no error in the code.  If I just plainly build and run it, it works properly.  It is when I run in "debug" mode the program does not stop in the breakpoint I set and Python complains about crashing....in other words, debug mode does not work with Qt on Yosemite on my MAC and this is a fresh install....

Comment: Try launching XCode.

Comment: Hi I just tried having Xcode opened while debugging with Qt.  It still crashes Python and it still does not work.....

Comment: I use Eclipse with PyDev and it works well on windows. You may want to have a look at it. Quite straight forward, I had no problem debugging my code without doing something special.

Answer (score 1):

The shared library (.so) provided with the QT download unfortunately incompatible between Mavericks and Yosemite.
To fix this you need to compile Qt by yourself. Just follow these steps (you might have to adapt a little bit depending on your original Qt install):

```
git clone https://gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator.git 
cd qt-creator
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/${user}/Qt/5.4/clang_64/bin/
qmake
make
cd bin/Qt\ Creator.app/Contents/MacOS
./Qt\ Creator
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13803 which is fixed in the meantime.

Comment: You might explain the contents of that link in your answer. Just posting a link isn't really considered a good answer because links often dry up and that would leave future viewers without any idea of what was there or how this answer helped.